# And simple way to make Firefox and Safari to show favicon next to the bookmark title on the Bookmark bar?

Tags: mac, firefox, safari, bookmarks, favicon

I think it is a design decision that Firefox and Safari both don't show the favicon (the little icon for a website) next to the bookmark's title on the Bookmark bar.

(for example, if there is a "Google" bookmark on the Bookmark bar, they won't show the small Google icon to the left of the word "Google" on the Bookmark bar)

So I searched and saw that the only way seems to make it work is to install add-on for Firefox?  If it is a skin, then I feel more relaxed to use it, but if it is an Add-on, then can't there be potential security risk?

There is also mentioning that if we remove the name (change the name to nothing), then the favicon will show.  I tried but it didn't work for some reason.

Any simple way to make it work for Firefox and Safari?  Supposedly, a

```
Preferences -> Appearance -> Show favicons on bookmark bar
```

will do, but there seems to be no such choice?

Comment: If it's not there then that would seem to answer your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All of my bookmarks in Firefox show the favicon next to them. The only time I had an issue with them not showing was after I formatted and imported my bookmarks back in. I had to manually revisit the sites so that it could grab the favicon. There is probably something wrong on your end as I just checked my firefox and all my bookmarks have favicons.

*Also a suggestion, if you want more people to answer your questions you need to start accepting more than **19%** of the answers.*

Comment: I concur.   My Icons are showing fine in Firefox, in fact I do not have text next to them, just the icon, makes for a muck more compact bookmark bar.  Favicon are also showing in the bookmark menus and groups. But as Marcin stated you will need to visit the page once in order for the Firefox to pick it up.

Answer (score 1):

I spent quite a bit of time finding the answer... newly installed firefox and wanted favicons which don't import.

Slow answer is that they will load as you open each site.

Quick answer is an addon called CheckPlaces which scans all sites and loads favicons where found (and some other good things like finding duplicates, etc)